# Graphing Millions of Points

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I am attempting to plot millions of points in a scatterplot, in such a way that the graph can be zoomed in on to explore the inner structure. Does anyone have any tips on a way that this can be done on a mac without programming knowledge? Thanks!!

Comment: Idea: MATLAB language and write a 3-lines code to plot your scatterplot.

Comment: I've tried with Mathematica, but it seems to be much more than it can handle... and there is no interactive zooming. Would MATLAB be significantly different?

Comment: I have no idea about the limit of points for scatterplot, however I think it is definitely more than Mathematica. I recommend you to at least try.

Comment: Create an image in PNG format and then use a zooming viewer?

Comment: Your video adapter may be the limiting factor rather than the software you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can download "Graphing Calculator 3D" software to plot clouds of large set of 3d scatter points.

It allows you to import *.csv files that contain x,y,z points or simply copy and paste your x,y,z rows from an Excel sheet document.

The result will be rendered super-fast in real-time so you can use your mouse to rotate the axis and zoom in and out fast and smoothly.

Here is an screenshot of one such graph generated by this software: [Graph of 3D scatter points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b11hu.png).